# Initialization of dynamic memory c++

Tags: c++

In below code, I expect `1` to be initialized in all the `10` elements in `x` array. But, it doesn't seem to be working. May I know what I am missing here?

```
int main() {
int *x = new int[10];

for(int i =0; i <10; ++i){
    *x = 1;
    x++;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    std::cout<<i<<" is "<<x[i]<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the time you end the initialization loop, your x is pointing beyond the last allocated element. Before second forloop you need to readjust x to point to start of memory

```
x -= 10;
```

Even better would be to keep your walking pointer as a copy

```
int *xcopy = x;
for(int i =0; i <10; ++i){
    *xcopy = 1;
    xcopy++;
}
```

Or use indexing to update the value

```
for(int i =0; i <10; ++i){
    x[i] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're incrementing `x` in the first loop, so after that it points past the end of the array. The second loop uses that new value to read from memory beyond the end, giving undefined behaviour.

The best option is to stop juggling pointers, with the bonus feature of fixing the memory leak:

```
std::vector<int> x(10, 1);
for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout<<i<<" is "<<x[i]<<std::endl;
}
```

Otherwise, you could assign to `x[i]` rather than `*x` in the first loop and leave `x` unmodified; or you use a copy of the pointer, or undo the modification after the loop.

Comment: This is the best way without doubt to do this thing in `C++`

Answer (score 3):

Your code has undefined behavior, as you're accessing some random memory (you have changed `x`).

You should not change `x` (the pointer). Instead, you can use `x[ i ] = 1;` or use some other temp pointer to "loop over" x.

You can also decrement `x`, as @Mohit Jain states, but I wouldn't recommend changing where `x` points at all.